# How to make bitbucket web hook point to localhost?

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks

I'm trying to write a web-hook to publish repository push events to my local server (for testing). The problem is, the web-hook on the bitbucket UI takes in a URL, and my server is running on localhost - what do I put in the URL box? Do I input my computer IP, followed by port?

So, something like:

http://129.123.3.1:8080/webHookUrl

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need configured your reverse proxy in your server (apache, tomcat, jetty, ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If port is the problem, you need an URL without port, where your server is available. The easiest way to do that is to use [ngrok](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/#using-ngrok). Admin guru would recommend you something more secured and serious. For example, setup and configure Apache HTTP Server. But it's another topic. 
Actually, I would recommend to read detailed explanation of [how to setup Github web hooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/). Bitbucket works in a very similar way(unfortunately, Bitbucket is not so well documented).

Comment: Wow, this github documentation is so much better than bitbuckets. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this document. It's clear and not intimidating